# Should I use my front brakes continuously or intermittently?

Tags: motorcycle, brakes

One of my friends has been instructed by the dealer's staff of a reputed two wheeler manufacturer not to apply/engage the front disk brake continuously. Instead, engage  the brake intermittently.

The fact that most of the braking power comes from the front brakes got me thinking, why are they advised so?

Comment: Would anyone please add the relevent tags, I cannot find them in my browser.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic since this is a question about driving technique.

Comment: I think this represents an intersection of technique and understanding of the mechanics of the brakes. Might be worth keeping open if answers lead to a discussion of the system and how it works

Answer (score 2):

Without clarification of exactly what they said, it is possible they were referring to light braking to simply slow down without stopping, rather than hard stopping or panic braking. Personally, I don't use the front brake unless I intend to come to a full stop. To slow down, I reduce the throttle to let the engine slow the bike or apply some rear brake.

Yes, the front brake does 60 - 80% of the braking work. Considering that the weight transfers to the front when braking, using too much or only the rear brake can cause you to lose control as the weight is transferred off the rear wheel.

The rider needs to apply brakes progressively (some call it staged braking) to stop without locking either wheel. This takes practice and skill to be able to do it in a panic stop. These techniques are taught in rider safety courses. Some people practice in an empty parking lot to be proficient so react more naturally (automatic) in case of and emergency stop.

Sources of additional information:

[Motorcycle Factors: Braking](http://www.nhtsa.gov/people/injury/pedbimot/motorcycle/00-NHT-212-motorcycle/motorcycle45-46.html)

[Motorcycle Braking Tips](http://www.webbikeworld.com/Motorcycle-Safety/braking-tips.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The only place I can see this advice would be useful is if you're going downhill. Using the brake intermittently will give it a chance to cool down between applications. For normal stops on level roads this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: For a given average braking power, the brakes used intermittently get time to cool when not applied, but when applied, they heat much more because the same braking power is applied in a shorter period of time.